# ruby Elegantly wrap an array of items each into an object

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given:

```
class Thing
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object   
  end
end

items = [1,2,3]
```

I'd like to know of a more elegant way to convert each item to the Thing than this:

```
items.map{ |item| Thing.new item }
# => [<Thing @object=1>, <Thing @object=2>, <Thing @object=3>]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the unary prefix `&` operator:

```
items.map(&Thing.method(:new))
```

[I have suggested that `Class`es should behave as *Factory Functions*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11262), which would allow you to write it like this:

```
items.map(&Thing)
```

However, there doesn't seem to be much interest in the proposal. You can monkey-patch it yourself, though, the implementation is trivial:

```
class Class
  def to_proc
    method(:new).to_proc
  end
end
```

Comment: Although I'm leery of monkey-patching (mainly because I'm not familiar enough to know when it's okay practice), The first example works wonderfully.  Thank you.

Comment: Your proposal is fascinating!

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that your example is perfectly fine. But perhaps you like something like this:

```
# in item.rb
def to_thing
  Thing.new(self)
end
```

That would allow you to write:

```
items.map(&:to_thing)
```